# Calling JSON data file by city name using httpClient method

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-httpclient

I have a file nameed `data.JSON` which currently sits in assets folder and has data structure like below

```
 {
      "id": 658,
      "first_name": "Stephen",
      "last_name": "Mapstone",
      "city": "London"
  }
```

I want to be able to call the JSON file above and get users by city name using httpClient method. something like below. How can i get a city name out of a JSON file using get method.

```
getUsers() {

  this.httpClient.get(`assets/data.json/${city}`).subscribe(
    (data: any[]) => {
        console.log(data);

});
}
```

complete project is available at [stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-post-t4uekz)

Comment: So what does or doesn’t work about your current code?

Comment: @deceze if you have read my question properly it clearly says i want to be able to call json file and get user by city name and how can i get it. i have also attached stack blitz link for users to test my code and suggest what changes needed for me to be able to get a user out of JSON file.

Comment: Your code mostly seems to do it. What exactly *doesn't* it do that you’re stuck on?

Comment: @Sammy: Angular HTTP client doesn't support fetching a single property from an object. You need to retrieve the object and pipe in a map it to return the desired property: `this.httpClient.get('assets/data.json').pipe(map(res => res['city'])).subscribe(...`. BTW `data: any[]` is wrong, you aren't expecting an array but an object. And with the map in place it's now a string. It should be `data: string`, the type of the property `city`. If you're new to Angular go through the tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.

Comment: @MichaelD tanks i tried your solution but result is undefined?   ```this.httpClient.get('assets/data.json').pipe(map(res => res['city'])).subscribe(result => { console.log(result); ```

Comment: @Sammy: Looking at your Stackblitz, you have an array of objects in the file, not a single object. More things need to be fixed in the code and the comment section doesn't suffice for it. And the question isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelD i  updated the stackBlitz and changed the array of objects to single object and your solution works. i guess the question is how do i get list of users if i  have array of objects in my data.json file ?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-post-t4uekz